# Do I need an I-Q (in-phase/quadrature) mapper in Simulink with the QAM modulator?

Tags: matlab

- Would it be correct if I use the `Random Integer Generator` block with a certain $M$-ary number (say $M=16$) followed directly by the `General QAM Modulator Baseband` block?
- I saw an example where they use an IQ mapper between the two blocks. Is it necessary?

I assumed the QAM block already does the mapping (inherently) because when I read the document it was specified that the input of the QAM modulator block should be an integer between $0$ and $M-1$, with no mention of the IQ  mapping.

[image: Capture]

Comment: The QAM block has two inputs, right? Each input should be an integer between 0 and $M-1$; one specifies the in-phase amplitude and the other the quadrature amplitude.

Comment: @MBaz No it has only one input

Comment: Right, I was looking at an old book. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the mapper. The Simulink QAM modulator lets you specify a vector of constellation points. The input should be an integer (or vector of integers) that select elements from the constellation points.

By default the block specifies a 8-PSK constellation. If you want something different, you need to provide the vector of constellation points.